# Ingore case-sensitive when using substr_count in php

Tags: php, html

I am making a word counter program, so if the user type a word like ("hello") in a textbox and submit the form (html), the program will search and count the number of times it appears on a specific webpage.
i have this code, is in spanish, so i will traslate it for you.

```
<?php

/*if the user submit, do this...*/ 

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

/*no warnings*/ 

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING); 

$buscar = $_POST["texto"];

$pagina = $_POST["Web"];

$buscar2 = strtolower($buscar);

/*no special characters like !hello!*/

$buscar2 = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $buscar2);

/*if the webpage doesn't exist, display this message*/

$headers = @get_headers($pagina);

if(strpos($headers[0],'200')===false)

{echo "Página no válida.";}else{ 

/*Get all content from the webpage*/

$web = file_get_contents($pagina);

/*Word - count the number of times it appears on a webpage*/

$result = (substr_count(strip_tags($web), $buscar2));

/*Display results*/

if($result == 0){

echo "La palabra " .strtoupper($buscar2). " no aparece";   

}else{

echo "La palabra " .strtoupper($buscar2). " aparece: $result veces";
}
}
}
?>
```

My question is, it is possible to ignore case when you search on a webpage, 
                     for example: hello-hEllo-Hello are the same.

Comment: sidenote: `if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

/*no warnings*/ 

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);` that will only appear if the input is clicked. If that submit isn't named, your code will fail silently. Place error checking on the first line; always/regardless.

Comment: and `@` are error suppressors btw and the html form is unknown.

Comment: You should lowercase both word and the text. That's how you can search case insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this natively. I would simply do this:

```
substr_count(strtolower($haystack), strtolower($needle));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a case insensitive `substr_count` function, why not just use `strtolower` to transform the input in an case invariant form.

```
$count = substr_count(strtolower($haystack), strtolower($needle));
```